# Sync /etc/hosts file across multiple machines

Tags: configuration, synchronization, alias, mirroring, hosts

Does anyone know an easy way to synchronize your /etc/hosts file across multiple machines? I use a MacBook, a MacMini, a Windows Machine as well as a Linux VM to develop websites with so it would be ideal to have all of them have the same hosts config.

Comment: If you are not asking how to write a program to accomplish this task, it belongs on http://superuser.com, not StackOverflow.

Comment: What you are looking for is configuration management tools.
One of the tool is known  as puppet.You can read this thread 
http://serverfault.com/questions/94104/are-configuration-management-tools-puppet-chef-capable-of-keeping-installed-pa to know more about configuration management tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having a /etc/hosts file for each machine you might instead consider using a DNS server.

Comment: Any chance you could point someone a direction to figure out what this means in practice? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run rsync on any of the macs/linux, and [deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) on windows